# Spring boot multiple datasources

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, datasource

I have a problem with an application using spring boot in 1.5.1 version.

My application need to communicate with 2 databases (Oracle and MySQL)

My application use 2 datasources :
     - MySQL datasource

```
@Configuration
public class OracleDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "oracleDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_oracle") 
    public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
        return  DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "oracleJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("oracleDb") DataSource dsOracle) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsOracle);
    }
}
```

- Oracle datasource

  @Configuration
      public class MySQLDBConfig {

  ```
      @Bean(name = "mysqlDb")
      @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.ds_mysql")
      public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
          return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
      }

      @Bean(name = "mysqlJdbcTemplate")
      public JdbcTemplate mySQLjdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("mysqlDb")DataSource dsMySQL) {
          return new JdbcTemplate(dsMySQL);
      }
  }
  ```

I have defined the 2 datasources in my applications.properties by using the prefix.

When I launch the program I have this error :

```
Parameter 0 of method oracleJdbcTemplate in com.bv.aircraft.config.OracleDBConfig required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - mysqlDb: defined by method 'mysqlDataSource' in class path resource [com/bv/aircraft/config/MySQLDBConfig.class]
    - oracleDb: defined by method 'oracleDataSource' in class path resource [com/bv/aircraft/config/OracleDBConfig.class]
```

I have tried to use @Primary but it is not working when i need to use the other datasource.

Thank you

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following in your spring boot configuration class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: By default spring boot enable DatasourceAutoConfiguration which initializes DatasourceInitializer to run schema.sql and data.sql from classpath. And this requires a single or primary datasource which was missing in your case. So needed to disable that.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

separate the template configuration from the datasource configuration and inject in the two datasources with qualifiers into the template configuration, or just call the create datasource method directly, e.g.

```
public JdbcTemplate oracleJdbcTemplate(oracleDataSource()) DataSource dsOracle) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsOracle);
}
```